# Not able to get variable to function in map input

Tags: python, variables

How can i get **variable** to work in below code:

```
variable_data = 300
values = list(map(int, input('Enter two numbers {variable_data}: ').split())
a = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else 100
b = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else 200

result:
Enter two numbers {variable_data}:
```

Comment: You have a bracket missing at the end of  `values = ...`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

There is multiple solution.

First of all, you can use a f-string:

```py
# You can use [*map] and not list(map) since Python 3.5, it's shorter
values = [*map(int, input(f'Enter two numbers {variable_data}: ').split())]
```

You can also manually concatenate an int to string:

```py
values = [*map(int, input('Enter two numbers '+str(variable_data)+': ').split())]
```

But f-strings are the best option in this case.

So, this will look like that:

```py
variable_data = 300
values = [*map(int, input(f'Enter two numbers {variable_data}: ').split())] # Enter two numbers 300: 
a = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else 100
b = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else 200
```

Answer (score 1):

use f-string

```
variable_data = 300
entry = input(f'Enter two numbers {variable_data}: ').split()
values = list(map(int, entry))
a = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else 100
b = values[0] if len(values) > 0 else 200
```